# Angular 2 animations pass an Input

Tags: javascript, angular, animation

I need a way to configure my animations dynamically. For example, I want my consumer to be able to pass as Input of the numbers of the animate declaration or any CSS property.

```
     animations: [
        trigger('heroState', [
          state('inactive', style({
            backgroundColor: '#eee',
            transform: this.transform
          })),
          state('active',   style({
            backgroundColor: '#cfd8dc',
            transform: this.transform
          })),
          transition('inactive => active', animate(this.animateInActive),
          transition('active => inactive', animate('100ms ease-out'))
        ])
      ]

      class Cmp {
        @Input() transform = 'scale(1)';
        @Input() animateInActive = '200ms ease-out';
      }
```

Comment: I personally found it easier (and a lot more robust) to bundle in animate.css and just dynamically set classes using ngClass. Very easy and works really well.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use ngClass for more complicated stuff

Comment: Sure you can. I conditionally combine a handful of my own classes and the animate.css classes easily, even changing them on the fly. Sometimes they animate, sometimes they don't. In the end, all ngClass does is bind to a string value that is a space-separated list of classes. It works great and you get a lot more animation options. In fact, the ngAnimate (or whatever it is) service is based on animate.css I believe. I have two websites with animation, one I do it the "angular" way, one I just bundle in animate.css, and I find the animate.css way much easier all around.

Comment: It seems that issues related to dynamic bindings in animation are still open.

Comment: This is sucks. I expected it to be obvious.